# How to know how many reusable cells the current UITableView have?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been using UITableView's `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` without much thinking, and it's been working fine.

But for my new project I need to maintain multiple reusable cells. By accident I ended up creating a reusable cell for each row, and surprisingly enough it's working fine with no problem so far with around 20 rows.

Basically there's no "reuse" going on since it creates a reusable cell for each distinct cell, which means it keeps all of them in memory. I'm trying to fix this, but first want to make sure that when I do fix it, I can see the concrete number as evidence.

So I was wondering if there's an API or any other way to find out how many "deque-able" reusable cells the current UITableView is holding in memory. Thanks!

EDIT:

Maybe this description is confusing. Let me clarify. Let's say I have this code:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++){
  NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil)
  {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier;
  }
}
```

This code effectively creates 1000 distinct reusable UITableViewCells.

I know this is bad, **but that is NOT the point of this question.**

Instead what I am looking for is: some way to find out how many of these UITableViewCells are in memory (probably held by the `tableView` object).

---

EDIT #2:

I think my code has brought even more confusion. Let me try to fix this with more detailed code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  ...

  NSString *cellIdentifier = [self.item objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil)
  {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier;
  }

  ...
}
```

In above code, let's say `self.item` is an array of 1000 distinct strings. In this case, when you start scrolling, it will look for a `reusable cell` with each string ad its identifier.

The first time it displays on the screen it won't find it, so it will `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` to create them.

As you scroll through all 1000, since there will be no cell with the cellIdentifier each time, the `cell` variable will **always be nil**. This is why it will keep creating up to 1000 UITableViewCells to be "dequeued".

Once you reach the end of the 1000 items, and start scrolling back up, the tableview will again start looking up UITableViewCell instances with each identifier. This time they all exist in memory, so the `cell` will always be NOT nil.

I am not pulling this out of my imagination. I found out by mistakenly getting myself into this situation. And sure enough, it never hits the `initWithStyle:` part once I reach the end of the list and start scrolling back up.

This is why I wanted a way to know if there's a way to count the number of dequeueable cells in memory.

Comment: Are you talking about `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];`? I think you should be able to use more than one `cellIdentifier` in your case.

Comment: Yes I am talking about that. But my question is more about "how to know the number of reusable cells that the current tableview is holding in memory?" Because you can instantiate these cells with multiple cellIdentifiers (for example by looping through a for loop). I'm sure they're somewhere on memory, but can't seem to find a way to enumerate these "cellIdentifiers" or the reusable cells themselves

Comment: I don't understand. If you use only one `cellIdentifier` it should save only one reusable cell in the memory, and try to use that cell from that moment. No?

Comment: OK I updated the question to clarify what I'm asking. I'm not asking for a solution to make the code work better. I already know how to do that. I am looking for a way to count the reusable UITableViewCells currently in memory.

Comment: You can get your cell class to increase some counter in a singleton or global when it is created and decrement it when it is deinited

Comment: @Paulw11 that's a good point, I think I may try that. But ultimately, I'm looking for some magic API for tableView (or an XCode feature) that I can use to just get the UITableViewCells. Is there no such thing?

Comment: Actually the table view is supposed to create as many reusable cells as the number of visible cells.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the count of `UITableViewCells` in memory is equal to the count you see on device's screen. When cells move out of screen they are removed from memory, and when `UITableView` needs more cells they are created again, possibly by using reusable cell.

Comment: Guys I updated the question yet again, because I think my last update made it even more confusing. Hopefully this is clearer now.

Comment: The tableView just instantiates cells as needed and I don't think it exposes any count properties. It's generally 2 or 3 more than will fit on the screen once it's scrolled. You could try asking the UITableViewCell class object how many instances are in memory. Or log the cell's memory address inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and see how many cells print before repeating a memory address.